# Is there a way to detect that an Apex test is running within the packaging process?

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package

We are hitting some <strike>CPU limit challenges</strike> [undocumented limits that are shared amongst all executed code during the course of a runAllTests request](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BVVaIAO) and would like to automatically turn some tests off during the packaging - packaging 1 or 2 - process.

Is there a way to detect this situation directly from Apex code?

FYI:

- Using e.g. a custom setting switch would be problematic as we need to make the change in patch versions too.
- We could look for a "magic" string in the username used for packaging but that feels hacky.

Comment: You probably should have guessed what's coming, but I'm going to do it anyways: This is apparently an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). A test that fails while packaging should also fail when not packaging (at least, in theory). It sounds like you have a test that is using more than 10 seconds, but less than 20 seconds, thus could randomly fail depending on the org. The solution is likely optimization of the tests involved. I could be wrong, though, but without some code to reproduce the issue, hard to tell.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I had mis-stated the problem - see the link I've just added. The idea is to run all tests via Jenkins (to guarantee functionality) and a subset that still achieves >75% coverage when packaging.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, the only real option is to reduce/eliminate redundant DML and SOQL operations as much as possible. This includes using @testSetup annotations to create records, dependency injection when possible to create "fake" records when possible, and creating a trigger framework that can enable/disable triggers in memory without the use of Custom Settings. Doing so will not only avoid this error, but also reduce packaging and Run All Tests (RAT) times. If your tests are taking longer than an hour to complete, that's far too much work being done.

Comment: Dependency injection first and foremost. Touching the database on either end tends to be where most time is spent in my experience.

Comment: The tests take less than 30 minutes as we normally run them in parallel. But packing turns that off so a couple of hours there. Agreed that refactoring is a solution, but with 4,000+ tests that is no small matter. I've asked my colleague to figure out why we are OK in Jenkins but not when packaging. That isn't clear to me.

Comment: @KeithC Yikes, that sounds painful. As a quick fix, I would definitely recommend a trigger disabling framework. It's only about 30-ish lines of code for a decent framework, and then a sprinkling of code everywhere else. It's certainly doable, but you've got a mountain of work ahead of you any way you slice it.